# iOS: transparent background modal in storyboard using UIModalPresentationCurrentContext not working

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, modalviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, uiviewanimationtransition

I've seen a bunch of examples on SO that do the same thing in a custom `UIStoryBoardSegue`'s `perform` method to implement a modal with a transparent background, but when I try doing this, as soon as the animation finishes and presentViewController is called, the modal's black background instantly comes right back. Here's the code:

```
- (void)perform {
    UIViewController *sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController;

    sourceViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

    [sourceViewController.view addSubview:destinationViewController.view];
    destinationViewController.view.alpha = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        destinationViewController.view.alpha = 1;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [destinationViewController.view removeFromSuperview];

        // boom, the black background returns!
        [sourceViewController presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO completion:^{
            // these have no effect
            destinationViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            destinationViewController.view.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        }];
    }];
}
```

I'm also setting the modal presentationStyle to "Current Context" in the source VC through IB:

[image]

I'm not using a `UINavigationController`.

As you can see I've tried setting the background color of the destination view controller, the superview of the destination view controller, setting `.modalPresentationStyle` on the sourceViewController *and* destinationViewController, but nothing seems to work!

If I comment out the part that removes the destination view from its superview, and the `presentViewController:` call, everything works fine, but then destination VC is dealloc'ed so I'm unable to interact with it and/or unwind it later. Really at a loss here.

**Edit:** Another issue I'm seeing in the console after going this route is an `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UIViewController: 0x7f86a042c114>.` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved:

So it looks like there's no way (as far as I can tell) to perform a custom modal segue with a transparent background completely contained within the `perform` method.

The solution was to set my custom segue as the `transitionDelegate` inside `perform` and then do the animation in `animateTransition:` instead. Finally, call `[transitionContext completeTransition:YES];` after the animation has finished.

After doing this, the "Unbalanced calls..." error also went away.